# How can I pg_dump my database while excluding extensions?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pg-dump

I am trying to migrate my PostgreSQL 9.3 database to heroku.

My database uses the UUID-ossp contrib extension

I am not able to load my db onto Heroku because

```
ERROR:  permission denied for language c
```

on

```
-- Name: uuid_generate_v1(); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: -
--
CREATE FUNCTION uuid_generate_v1() RETURNS uuid
    LANGUAGE c STRICT
    AS '$libdir/uuid-ossp', 'uuid_generate_v1';
```

I understand I can simply

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

in my database.  But how can i exclude the various UUID functions from my pg_dump in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've installed the ossp-uuid extension from the sql scripts directly, rather than with `create extension`.

You should `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" FROM unpackaged;` on your local DB, before creating the dump. That'll convert it into an extension, which is dumped as `CREATE EXTENSION ...` instead of individual `CREATE FUNCTION ...` commands.